# Browser back button angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, back, browser-history

I want to get working back button of the browser with angular 1.4.10 ui-router.

This is sample code of my app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[ "ui.router", "AppCtrls"]);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
    $stateProvider.state("state1", {
        url: "",
        template: "<p>State 1</p>",
        controller: "Ctrl1"
      }).state("state2", {
        url: "",
        template: "<p>State 2</p>",
        controller: "Ctrl2"
      });
});

var ctrls = angular.module("AppCtrls", []);

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl1", function($scope) {
    console.log("Ctrl1 loaded.");
});

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl2", function($scope) {
    console.log("Ctrl2 loaded.");
});
```

When I am giving URL to each state back button works well but when I have not given any URL to each state back button is not working.

Is there any workaround to get back button working without having URL of state?